# Ошибка invalid hash при сохранении фотографии на стене группы

Tags: vkontakte-api, php, вконтакте

Делаю все вроде по документации. Сначала получаю адрес сервера для загрузки фото

```
$sRequest = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?group_id=".$group_id."&access_token=".$access_token;
```

потом формирую POST запрос на этот адрес

```
    $post_params = array(
  'file1' => '@'.$photoPath2,
  );
  $ch = curl_init( $oResponce->response->upload_url );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
  $response = curl_exec( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );
```

Все это работает как надо, в ответ возвращаются данные такого вида `string(538) "{"server":759255,"photo":"[{\"photo\":\"5c0ee7b56f:x\",\"sizes\":[[\"s\",\"618520954\",\"a410\",\"Iosmd2gQnbE\",75,46],[\"m\",\"618520954\",\"a411\",\"Rtee5OfIEAI\",130,80],[\"x\",\"618520954\",\"a412\",\"YBQDYZywmI0\",550,337],[\"o\",\"618520954\",\"a413\",\"x-oLJQgm2RI\",130,87],[\"p\",\"618520954\",\"a414\",\"P2urHyRL8vw\",200,133],[\"q\",\"618520954\",\"a415\",\"281yPf5bAc0\",320,213],[\"r\",\"618520954\",\"a416\",\"JdxpKBE6ih8\",510,337]],\"kid\":\"62ebb35ee2e5395151f63bd0d8efbae0\"}]","hash":"7ab875310ab0cb8e53d3fd4ba6e5369b"}"` - это строка, которую я распиливаю на отдельные составляющие server photo и hash. В переменную $server попадает значение 759255, в `$photo - 5c0ee7b56f`, в `hash - 7ab875310ab0cb8e53d3fd4ba6e5369b`. Затем вызываю метод `photos.saveWallPhoto`

```
    $rsRequest = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/photos.saveWallPhoto?group_id=".$group_id."&access_token=".$access_token."&photo=".$photo."&server=".$server."&hash=".$hash;
  $roResponce = json_decode(file_get_contents($rsRequest));
  var_dump($roResponce);
```

И каждый раз ловлю ошибку Invalid hash. Что я делаю не так? Вроде все по документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам цитата из документации

> Обратите внимание, что ответ сервера
> всегда приходит в формате JSON, а поля
> server, photo и hash в нем содержат
> строки, внутренний формат которых
> может изменяться со временем. В
> частности, строка photo может
> содержать другой json-объект, который
> не следует декодировать, разбирать на
> части или иным образом модифицировать.

То есть `photo` должно попасть

```
"[{\"photo\":\"5c0ee7b56f:x\",\"sizes\":[[\"s\",\"618520954\",\"a410\",\"Iosmd2gQnbE\",75,46],[\"m\",\"618520954\",\"a411\",\"Rtee5OfIEAI\",130,80],[\"x\",\"618520954\",\"a412\",\"YBQDYZywmI0\",550,337],[\"o\",\"618520954\",\"a413\",\"x-oLJQgm2RI\",130,87],[\"p\",\"618520954\",\"a414\",\"P2urHyRL8vw\",200,133],[\"q\",\"618520954\",\"a415\",\"281yPf5bAc0\",320,213],[\"r\",\"618520954\",\"a416\",\"JdxpKBE6ih8\",510,337]],\"kid\":\"62ebb35ee2e5395151f63bd0d8efbae0\"}]"
```

Comment: блин, но данные же возвращаются в виде строки. Как ее тогда разбить на три отдельные переменные server, hash и photo если разбивать нельзя?

Comment: @kuchuluk возвращается json-объект c тремя полями: server, photo и hash. Поле photo содержит вложенный json объект представленный в виде строки. Этот json объект тоже содержит поле photo. Вы путаете эти два поля. В документации речь идёт о том, что в корне объекта.

Answer (score 0):

```
upload_url = self.vk_api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=config.vk_group_id, v='5.73')['upload_url']
    request = requests.post(upload_url, files={'photo': open("Penguins.jpg", "rb")})
    print(request.json())
    params = {'server': request.json()['server'],
              'photo': request.json()['photo'],
              'hash': request.json()['hash'],
              'group_id': -config.vk_group_id,
              'v': '5.73'}

    photo_id = self.vk_api.photos.saveWallPhoto(**params)[0]['id']

    params = {'attachments': photo_id,
              'owner_id': config.vk_group_id,
              'from_group': '1'}
    self.vk_group_api.wall.post(**params)
```

как автор отправляю изображение, в saveWallPhoto как и советуют прокидываю полное поле photo из предыдущего шага, но ошибка всё равно:

vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 121. Invalid hash. request_params = {'oauth': '1', 'method': 'photos.saveWallPhoto', 'server': '834404', 'photo': '[{"photo":"43ed4dc030:z","sizes":[["s",834404069,"da1c1","uzrHSo8nIKc",75,56],["m",834404069,"da1c2","aZlFxqlk0oI",130,97],["x",834404069,"da1c3","Zy9gTx0-Q44",604,453],["y",834404069,"da1c4","jJAuVJfldAU",807,605],["z",834404069,"da1c5","mK9RkdISm0Q",1024,768],["o",834404069,"da1c6","PjCSeZyvkaA",130,98],["p",834404069,"da1c7","FYkEimvmVK8",200,150],["q",834404069,"da1c8","ch3qZ-g67a0",320,240],["r",834404069,"da1c9","DTm4j2jrmoA",510,383]],"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"kid":"7e803bfa8287365ba577a42ab4e579f7"}]', 'hash': 'd9f5c3f00db055d84cd0bf52e9deb4c8', 'group_id': '********', 'v': '5.73'}

Answer (score -1):

```
json_decode(string(538) от этой переменной, true )
```

вернет массив где будут все параметры